# Password not filtered in log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

According to Rails documentation

> config.filter_parameters used for filtering out the parameters that
>   you don't want shown in the logs, such as passwords or credit card
>   numbers. By default, Rails filters out passwords by adding
>   `Rails.application.config.filter_parameters += [:password]` in
>   `config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb`. Parameters filter
>   works by partial matching regular expression.

So, why when I submit the form below

```
<%= form_with model: @user, url: admin_user_path, method: :delete do %>
    <%= label_tag :password, t('forms.password') %>
    <%= text_field_tag :password, nil %>
    <%= button_tag t('forms.save'), type: 'submit' %>
 <% end %>
```

I can see my password in the log?

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"delete", "authenticity_token"=>"r22P2Mi1xcWOjRHGogoFaDcOec9/FgkC9btCo66qmqaKG/zwzUkbUGtATsTKV19OOYK80VBf1h0CzFtoRltQOA==", "password"=>"x", "button"=>"", "controller"=>"admin/users", "action"=>"destroy", "id"=>"at-example-com"} permitted: false>
```

Shouldn't the password be [FILTERED]?

Comment: This is extremely well discussed https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115694/why-is-saying-thank-you-in-question-undesirable

Comment: @meagar Thank you for the link ;)

Answer (score 2):

The piece of code you're showing isn't from a log:

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "_method"=>"delete", "authenticity_token"=>"r22P2Mi1xcWOjRHGogoFaDcOec9/FgkC9btCo66qmqaKG/zwzUkbUGtATsTKV19OOYK80VBf1h0CzFtoRltQOA==", "password"=>"x", "button"=>"", "controller"=>"admin/users", "action"=>"destroy", "id"=>"at-example-com"} permitted: false>
```

That output from the command like `puts(params)`. The option `filter_parameters` is about log file which placed under `log` directory. E.g. `log/development.log`

Here is a piece of log file:

```
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"mxQJeccoEATtyCFy1eV", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"Juggy Head", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create user"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used `text_field_tag` (It's going to input type text) that's why it's showing value in the log you need to use `password_field_tag` (It's going to input type password) like below

```
<%= form_with model: @user, url: admin_user_path, method: :delete do %>
    <%= label_tag :password, t('forms.password') %>
    <%= password_field_tag :password, nil %>
    <%= button_tag t('forms.save'), type: 'submit' %>
<% end %>
```

Rails API doc [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/password_field_tag)

For instance, password filtering to use above code

**Update**

I completely agree with this [answer Зелёный](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48435589/4172515)

Comment: I'm afraid that is not the answer. As far as I know, you don't have to use `password_field_tag` to filter the values. For instance, you can filter credit card numbers and I don't know any single app that uses a `password_field_tag` to input credit card numbers. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I have searched and found some helpful links and one of this https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/03/07/parameter-filtering-enhacement-rails-5.html @macsig